# Exception when downloading huge files using struts framework

Tags: java, exception, struts2

Sorry if this question is similar to any other already present, I am posting this as none of the solutions offered have worked for me.

I have a struts action of type 'stream' called download, which leads to downloading a file from a website(running in HTTPS).

Code:

```
   InputStream inp; 
   public String execute {    
       inp = //get inputstream;
       return SUCCESS; 
   }

struts 
<action name="download" class="ABC">    
   <result name="SUCCESS" type="stream">
      <param name="contentType">application/octet-stream</param>
      <param name="inputName">inp</param>
      <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;fileName="abc"</param>
      <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>    
   </result>
</action>
```

For downloading very large files across browsers, it throws an exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:611)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:198)
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:122)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:125)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:118)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:180)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:118)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:77)  at org.apache.jsp.shared.baseerror_jsp._jspService(baseerror_jsp.java:87)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
        at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.include(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:217)
        at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:177)
        at org.apache.tiles.context.TilesRequestContextWrapper.dispatch(TilesRequestContextWrapper.java:72)
        at org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesRequestContext.dispatch(StrutsTilesRequestContext.java:88)
        at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:606)
        at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:246)
        at org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult.doExecute(TilesResult.java:105)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:373)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:277)
        at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:498)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:434)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:563)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:615)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

After the exception occurs, the file download stops in between and the user has an incomplete file.

When I google the issue, I see that many people have faced a similar issue, esp with IE, but none of the solutions offered seem to apply to my case(I am facing the issue across browsers).

Comment: Is this struts1 or struts2, there is a big difference.

Comment: In order to get help I think you should post the code in your action and the relevant parts of your struts configuration.

Comment: All that looks correct.  Do you have a more complete stacktrace?

Comment: Added the stack trace

Comment: Does your code work for smaller files ?

Comment: Yes, the code works for smaller files and throws exception only in case of large files.